# inner product of a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a dataframe.  I want to take the inner product of each column with itself and sum these up.

So far I've done this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed([3, 1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 3).round(2), columns=['one', 'two', 'three'])

inner_df = df.T.dot(df)
print inner_df
print

tot = 0
for i in range(len(inner_df)):
    tot += inner_df.iloc[i, i]

print "total =", tot

          one     two   three
one    3.7611  3.4669  3.4766
two    3.4669  3.6323  3.1140
three  3.4766  3.1140  3.5214

total = 10.9148
```

This gets me what I need, but it feels very clumsy.  What is a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: Better ask on code review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If the code works as intended (which appears to be the case), this would be OK on Code Review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vectorized solution looks like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed([3, 1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 3).round(2), columns=['one', 'two', 'three'])

# pandas approach
print df.mul(df).sum().sum()

# numpy approach
print np.square(df.values).sum()

10.9148
10.9148
```